# Need to reduce json data fetching time using Alamofire in swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

In my application I am working on Alamofire to fetch the data . I think it is taking little bit more time to fetch json data. I am adding my code here. Can anyone suggest me how to reduce the fetching time?

```
func getUserData(completion: @escaping LcodeResponseCompletion) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(LCODE_URL)")  else{return}
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue
        Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { (response) in
            if let error = response.result.error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = response.data else { return completion(nil)}
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let lcode = try jsonDecoder.decode(Empty.self, from: data)
                
                completion(lcode)
            } catch {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: What's taking time? The fetch (after all, an API call takes times, if you have low connection, server is busy, etc.). The decoding? Maybe pass the class to Alamofire, it might decode it in a background private queue instead of default main queue for the completion handler.

Comment: I'd suggest investigating your `URLSessionTaskMetrics` to see where your request time is being spent.

Comment: You can also print the `response` to see its `Timeline` (in Alamofire 4) or the metrics (in Alamofire 5).

Comment: ▿ timeline : Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 639422623.296, "Initial Response Time": 639422630.486, "Request Completed Time": 639422630.488, "Serialization Completed Time": 639422630.488, "Latency": 7.190 secs, "Request Duration": 7.192 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 7.192 secs }

Comment: can you please tell me why it is taking 7 seconds for a simple request? can we reduce the time ?

Comment: `"Latency": 7.190 secs` This means the server took 7 seconds to answer to the request. Issue is with the server, not with your code.